# Re-exporting from multiple modules in ES5

Tags: ecmascript-5, es6-modules, es5-compatiblity

I have index.js with the following code that works fine on the client, re-exporting functions defined in three other modules:

```
export * from './validators';
export * from './comparators';
export * from './transforms';
```

But I want to use these in NodeJS. Our current version, at least, appears not to know this ES6 syntax. I know, in the modules where the functions are defined, how to export them using

```
module.exports = {
    func1,
    func2
}
```

But what's the corresponding syntax for use in the re-exporting module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple but effective solution would be

```
Object.assign(module.exports,
    require('./validators'),
    require('./comparators'),
    require('./transforms'),
);
```

This is similar to what ES6 does, but does not support updating of exported members. For a closer approximation, you'd need to use getters or a proxy.

Of course there's a good alternative: just write ES6 syntax and use a transpiler that knows how to properly translate it to ES5!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Bergi, that solution worked. I'd also just worked out the following nearly equivalent one but my version has more typing:

```
const validators = require('./validators');
const comparators = require('./comparators');
const transforms = require('./transforms');

module.exports = {
    ...validators,
    ...comparators,
    ...transforms
};
```